# How to insert data into mysql using angular and nodejs - getting (NULL, NULL) upon insert - Problem solved

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, angularjs

Good day,

I've been trying to learn a bit of angular and nodejs. I found a tutorial on a realtime chat app and made some few adjustment to some function of the code. But the one aspect that I cannot seem to get right is the ability for the user to post to a feed. The login process works, the user is already logged in but the user can't post. I would also like to be able to get all they data i insert from all the user to show up like a normal feedview will. Please assist.

Here are my files:

FROM MY CONTROLLER HERE IS THE CODE WHEN THE BUTTON IS PRESSED

```
$scope.postDatatoDd = () => {

        appService.httpCall({
            url: '/posts',
            params: {
                'posts': $scope.data.info,
               'from_user_id': $scope.data.username
 }
        })
        .then((response) => {
           // $scope.$apply();

 })
        .catch((error) => {
            alert(error.message);
        });
    }
```

and here is my route file:

```
this.app.post('/posts', async(request,response) => {

            const reqResponse = {}
            const data = {
                posts : request.body.postDatatoDd,
                from_user_id: request.body.username

        
                
            };      
            if (data.posts === ''){
                reqResponse.error = true;
                reqResponse.message = `error, input`;
                response.status(412).json(reqResponse);
            } else {
                const result = await helper.insertFeed(data);

                
                if (result === null) {
                    reqResponse.error = true;
                    reqResponse.message = `they was an error.`;
                    response.status(417).json(reqResponse);
                } else {
                    reqResponse.error = false;
                    reqResponse.userId = result.insertId;
                    reqResponse.message = `posted succesfully`;
                    response.status(200).json(reqResponse);
                }

            }});
```

and in my helper file there is this function to insert data:

```
async insertFeed(params){
        try {
            return await this.db.query(
                `INSERT INTO posts (from_user_id,posts) values (?,?)`,
                [params.from_user_id,params.postDatatoDd]
            );
        } catch (error) {
            console.warn(error);
            return null;
        }       
    }
```

On the client side here is the button with :

```
 <label for="postDatatoDd">Post</label>
            <input type="text" id="postDatatoDd"
            ng-model="data.postDatatoDd"
                class="feed form-control" 
                placeholder="post your data here?" 
            />
            <button ng-click="postDatatoDd()" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>

        </div>
```

--- EDIT 1---

Data is being inserted now, but it is receiving the values as (NULL, NULL).

--- EDIT 2 ---

After closely looking at the code and fixing some naming variables the code works fine, the data is being inserted in mysql as it should.

Comment: The error says that the table `posts` doesn't have a column named `posts`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, it is working but insert dating as NULL on the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than a lot of typos when it comes to the variables reference. The code seem to be fine.

Assuming that you using appservice class somewhere in your code and its functioned, then everything else will work.

You are getting the (NULL, NULL) because you are parsing parameters that are not being properly parsed out to your helper file, please close attention to that.

```
 appService
      .httpCall({
        url: "/posts",
        params: {
          posts: $scope.data.postbuzz,
          from_user_id: $scope.data.username,
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        $scope.$apply();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error.message);
      });
```

make sure that the data that you calling from this above function is similar to $scope parameter you passing in your route file that your requesting:

```
const data = {
posts : request.body.posts,
from_user_id: request.body.from_user_id}
```

and in your database helper class you running:

```
`INSERT INTO posts (from_user_id,post) values (?,?)`,
 [params.from_user_id,params.posts]
```

Hope this was helpful

You seem to have an understand already. your question may help a lot more people in the future.

Answer (score 0):

params should be as following, since the data object has properties `from_user_id` and `posts`

```
`INSERT INTO posts (from_user_id,posts) values (?, ?)`,
                [params.from_user_id,params.posts]
```

Might be useful https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: I doubt so, cause i am still passing two values, userid and the posts

Comment: Have you checked the website, the examples given uses single (?). Also, I agree with @Shihab about the error message you get. It does complain about the column name.

Comment: True. thanks for pointing that out, checking the query from posts to post worked. but they data is being inserted as NULL, NULL

Comment: Just noticed, your data is
const data = {
                posts : request.body.postDatatoDd,
                from_user_id: request.body.username
}

and your insertFeed params
[params.from_user_id,params.postDatatoDd]

shouldn't it be in the insertFeed 
from_user_id, posts

Comment: Hi @omegatrix thank you so much for being helpfull, i did notice that and did modify my data and the data is now being inserted correctly...now i'm fighting to get a all the data to appear in a list view

Comment: @omegatrix...please do submit your comment as the answer for me to accept it as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

--- EDIT 2 ---

After closely looking at the code and fixing some naming variables the code works fine, the data is being inserted in mysql as it should.

If you are new to Angular you can use the code as reference.